# Animation from orange to teal is not taking effect

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I'd like to animate an .svg image with css, changing between two colors. I attempted a tutorial here and css-tricks with no success. I believe my issue (or one of them) might be that I'm not targeting the right element in the .svg. But I've tried many different elements, ids, tags, tried using different images, and even tried making my own image. I'll share the relevant code below using my first choice .svg file:

```css
 @keyframes color-change {
            from {
                fill: #f4f00;
            }
            to {
                fill: #a4f4f4;
            }
        }
        #Layer_1, #adobe_illustrator_pgf {
            animation: color-change 4s infinite alternate linear;}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" 
            id="Layer_1" 
            xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" 
            xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" 
            xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
            x="0px" y="0px" 
            viewBox="0 0 750 750"
            style="enable-background:new 0 0 750 750;" 
            xml:space="preserve">
        <switch>
            <foreignObject 
                requiredExtensions="&ns_ai;" 
                x="0" 
                y="0" 
                width="1" 
                height="1">
                <i:pgfRef  
                    xlink:href="#adobe_illustrator_pgf">
                </i:pgfRef>
            </foreignObject>
```

Thank you!

Update: I created the svg I wanted and was definitely able to target the right id-- I was able to change the color to orange. But the animation from orange to teal is still not taking effect.

svg:

```css
  @keyframes color-change {
        from {
            fill: var(--secondary-color);
        }
        to {
            fill: var(--primary-color-lighter);
        }
    }
    #about__main--img__fleur {
        animation: color-change 4s infinite alternate linear;
    }
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 750 750" >  
<path style="fill:#ff4f00" d="m 158.31488,-2.2022728 c 91.01571,130.5628628  43.85069,121.0522128 12.21,230.0500028 h 8.42 c  82.76816,-249.50584 171.87632,-54.87233 123.86,-12.24  -51.62689,-90.80719 -96.81,12.24 -96.81,12.24 14.30301,2.24628  34.92456,17.33855 -5.51,23.74 -5.67801,35.22547  14.97807,58.61711 40.68,19.78 21.9137,62.34493  -56.60711,108.84523 -64.69,-19.78 h -9.64 c -5.46371,42.41119  45.01408,82.24554 -8.45,115.11 -45.63648,-28.05726  -15.31394,-61.97543 -8.59,-115.11 h -10.45 c  -11.44247,151.90592 -92.587302,60.58808 -64.690002,19.78  32.374092,54.98005 40.680002,-19.78 40.680002,-19.78  -34.128832,-6.82614 -22.687672,-19.12856 -5.51,-23.74  -43.888082,-101.86884 -96.816002,-12.24 -96.816002,-12.24  -48.014316,-52.93652 50.97435,-223.7694488 123.866002,12.24 h  9.23 c -11.49629,-82.82875 -92.252982,-101.39727  12.21,-230.0500028" id="about__main--img__fleur" sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccccccccccc" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, just corrected. I had tried experimenting with other properties to see if I could get them to work. Fill is what I'd like to change though.

Comment: So what's pgfRef? At the moment there doesn't seem to be anything that's drawn with a fill that would change colour i.e. you're not targetting anything that responds to a fill colour.

Comment: I targeted the ids from the .svg file. So if neither of those would respond to a fill color, is there something in the file that would, perhaps that I could assign an id to? Or should I change my approach altogether or find a different image with a more straightforward fill?

Comment: Mot shapes or text will respond to a fill colour. Shapes would be rect, circle, ellipse, path, polygon, polyline (along with line but lines aren't filled).

Comment: Got it, I will see if I can find or create an image comprised of shapes and report back. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I removed from svg `style =" fill: # ff4f00 "` since this style has more weight than styles of the same element in CSS

Assigned an identifier for path - `id =" Layer_1 "`

The rest is done more or less correctly. Pretty good for your first try.

Color change animation occurs when hovering over a shape

```css
#Layer_1 {
     fill:#ff4f00;
    }
    #Layer_1:hover {
    animation: color-change 2s infinite alternate linear;
    }
    @keyframes color-change {
        from {
            fill: #ff4f00;
        }
        to {
            fill: #a4f4f4;
        }
    }
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 750 750" >  
         <path id="Layer_1"  d="m 158.31488,-2.2022728 c 91.01571,130.5628628  43.85069,121.0522128 12.21,230.0500028 h 8.42 c  82.76816,-249.50584 171.87632,-54.87233 123.86,-12.24  -51.62689,-90.80719 -96.81,12.24 -96.81,12.24 14.30301,2.24628  34.92456,17.33855 -5.51,23.74 -5.67801,35.22547  14.97807,58.61711 40.68,19.78 21.9137,62.34493  -56.60711,108.84523 -64.69,-19.78 h -9.64 c -5.46371,42.41119  45.01408,82.24554 -8.45,115.11 -45.63648,-28.05726  -15.31394,-61.97543 -8.59,-115.11 h -10.45 c  -11.44247,151.90592 -92.587302,60.58808 -64.690002,19.78  32.374092,54.98005 40.680002,-19.78 40.680002,-19.78  -34.128832,-6.82614 -22.687672,-19.12856 -5.51,-23.74  -43.888082,-101.86884 -96.816002,-12.24 -96.816002,-12.24  -48.014316,-52.93652 50.97435,-223.7694488 123.866002,12.24 h  9.23 c -11.49629,-82.82875 -92.252982,-101.39727  12.21,-230.0500028" />
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

I have optimized your SVG code using the [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) utility. The file size has decreased several times.
This is to make the SVG take up less space on the HTML page.
The app is responsive. You can change its initial dimensions using the vw vh relative units in the parent container

```css
.container {
    width:50vw;
    height:50vh;
    }
    #Layer_1 {
     fill:#ff4f00;
    }
    #Layer_1:hover {
    animation: color-change 2s infinite alternate linear;
    }
    @keyframes color-change {
        from {
            fill: #ff4f00;
        }
        to {
            fill: #a4f4f4;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">     
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 750 750" >  
         <path id="Layer_1"  d="M158-2c91 130 44 121 13 230h8c83-250 172-55 124-12-52-91-97 12-97 12 14 2 35 17-6 24-5 35 15 58 41 19 22 63-56 109-65-19h-9c-6 42 45 82-9 115-45-28-15-62-8-115h-11c-11 151-92 60-64 19 32 55 40-19 40-19-34-7-22-20-5-24-44-102-97-12-97-12-48-53 51-224 124 12h9c-11-83-92-102 12-230" />
</svg>       
</div>
```

Comment: Robert and Alexandr's suggestions both helped, but didn't fully solve the problem. Ultimately, placing the entire svg code within the html, versus linked as an img, was the final step to a successful animation.

Comment: @Scaramouche I read your question carefully again and did not find anywhere that you were trying to add svg code to html using <img> tags Does your question look exactly like adding svg inline Does the application work? Therefore, it would be good to accept my answer as a solution.

Comment: Dev ka niche go, a vopros taksi be. But the answer is really awsome!